# Evitar registros Duplicados Ionic 4 + Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic

hola quien me pueda ayudar ya guardo mi registro en la base de datos, pero quiero que no me los duplique

Registrar.ts

```
  AddUser(value: { nombre: any; cedula: Key; direccion: any; 
 numero_contacto: any; }) {
  this.authService.AddUser(value)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.errorMessage = " ";
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/');
    this.successMessage = "Tu cuenta ha sido creada. Por favor Iniciar 
   sesión.";
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
    this.errorMessage = err.message;
    this.successMessage = "";
  })
  }
```

authentication.service.ts

```
AddUser(value: { nombre: any; cedula: any; direccion: any; numero_contacto: 
 any; }) {
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
       this.afs.collection('/Usuarios').add({
    name: value.nombre,
    cedula: value.cedula,
    direccion: value.direccion,
    numero_contacto: value.numero_contacto
  })
    .then((res) => {
      resolve(res)
    },
      (err) => reject(err))
})
```

}

html

Registrate

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="person" item-left></ion-icon>
  <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Nombres y Apellidos:</ion-label>
  <ion-input formControlName="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<div class="validation-errors">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.nombre">
    <div class="error-message"
      *ngIf="validations_form.get('nombre').hasError(validation.type) && (validations_form.get('nombre').dirty || validations_form.get('nombre').touched)">
      {{ validation.message }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>


<ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="square-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
  <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Cedula:</ion-label>
  <ion-input formControlName="cedula" type="text" placeholder="Cedula" name="cedula"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<div class="validation-errors">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.cedula">
    <div class="error-message"
      *ngIf="validations_form.get('cedula').hasError(validation.type) && (validations_form.get('cedula').dirty || validations_form.get('cedula').touched)">
      {{ validation.message }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>

<ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="pin" item-left></ion-icon>
  <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Dirección:</ion-label>
  <ion-input formControlName="direccion" type="text" placeholder="Dirección" name="direccion">
  </ion-input>
</ion-item>
<div class="validation-errors">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.direccion">
    <div class="error-message"
      *ngIf="validations_form.get('direccion').hasError(validation.type) && (validations_form.get('direccion').dirty || validations_form.get('direccion').touched)">
      {{ validation.message }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>





<ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="call" item-left></ion-icon>
  <ion-label color="primary" tacked>Numero de contacto:</ion-label>
  <ion-input formControlName="numero_contacto" type="text" placeholder="Numero de contacto" name="numero_contacto">
  </ion-input>
</ion-item>
<div class="validation-errors">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.numero_contacto">
    <div class="error-message"
      *ngIf="validations_form.get('numero_contacto').hasError(validation.type) && (validations_form.get('numero_contacto').dirty || validations_form.get('numero_contacto').touched)">
      {{ validation.message }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>



<ion-button class="submit-btn" type="submit" [disabled]="!validations_form.valid">Registro</ion-button>
<label class="error-message">{{errorMessage}}</label>
<label class="success-message">{{successMessage}}</label>
```

Intenta iniciar sesión.

Comment: Tendrás que validar antes de comunicar con firebase para un nuevo registro, que dicho nombre de usuario no existe ya en firebase.

Comment: perdona la ignorancia pero soy nuevo en Ionic, Angular y no tengo a mejor forma de hacer lo que me sugieres

Comment: Me refiero que antes de almacenar directamente en firebase el nick del usuario. Tendrás que traer toda la lista de usuarios de firebase y recorrerla para ver si hay coincidencias. Si no las hay (es un nick no usado) guardas. Si existe con anterioridad pues no llamas a firebase para almacenar (porque generaría un duplicado).